# Python: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mongodb

Asking for some help on this one.

```
def home(request):
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(settings.MONGO_SERVER)
    main_db = client[settings.MONGO_DATABASE]
    get_main_config = main_db.configurations.find_one({"name": "main_config"})

    return render(request, 'dashboard/home.html', {"data": get_main_config["homepage_urls"]})
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
render(request, 'dashboard/home.html', {"data": get_main_config["homepage_urls"]})
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Why the error occured on that line?
Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like `get_main_config` is `None`.  Are you sure that `main_db.configurations_find_one` doesn't ever return `None`?

Answer (score 1):

The error shows up when you use operator [] on a variable whose value is None. So it can only be `get_main_config`. Just print the variable to check.

Answer (score 0):

It means that `get_main_config` is of type `None` and `None` is not a subscriptable type. For an object to be subscriptable in Python it must support indexing (lists, tuples, strings etc. are subscriptable). Here, since `get_main_config` is `None` (which does not support indexing) and you are trying to access the key `'homepage_urls'` from it you end up with the error you got.

The `find_one` method you are using is designed to find a single document matching your query or return `None` if it could not find any. (https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#getting-a-single-document-with-find-one)

So, you may want to make sure that a document matching the query `{'name': 'main_config'}` actually exists in your database.